# Is Hystrix fallback implementation mandatory?

Tags: hystrix, fallback

I have a method calling a third party resource to retrieve a Dog object. If the call fails, I have no alternative path to return the Dog object.

So, what is the preferred apporach here:-
1. Implement hystrix fallback and return a null Dog object.
2. Hystrix will throw an exception when the call fails and with the catching of exception, null Dog object will be returned.

Option 1 or 2?
Is hystrix fallback a mandatory implementation requirement is you don't really have a fallback approach?
I think not, what's your opinion? What does hystrix guidelines suggest?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, both options 1 and 2 result in the same outcome - a null Dog being returned. I would say that handling it using a fallback in such case is better because it's cleaner. Fallback will be defined as part of the command, and as such would be consistent among all the uses of this command. This would not be true if you handled it as an exception. In that case you would need to remember to implement the exception handling in all of the places where the call is made.. and in the same way - and it's easy to make a mistake by forgetting about handling some place.

Is it mandatory to have a fallback?
It's not mandatory. If not provided, an exception will be raised.
In your case, you do have a fallback strategy - it is just very simple. It is actually covered in the Hystrix Wiki as a Silent Fail and you can read more about it on https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Common-Patterns-FailSilent

It is worth to think about which operations need a fallback, or rather, what the fallback should be. It is worth providing a fallback for a read operation. For a write operation it may not be a good idea, as described here: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Fallback.

Defining a fallback strategy is part of the pattern. Imagine a project with few developers where Hystrix is used. It will feel nice to know where exactly to go to see the fallback strategy. That is a huge benefit.

One thing to keep in mind is that exceptions are more expensive to process so using them as a fallback strategy is a waste of resources. This won't be an issue in a small project with a small number of requests, but could cause problems in a system that processes a lot of such calls.